# In kubernetes whether it is possible to create cross region cluster in aws?

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes

Is there any possible to create master node in one region and worker node in another region in AWS ? If yes can someone Please tell how or if no can anyone give reason for that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would be possible but **on-prem** only and not by using **cloud**.

So in short: it is impossible to use nodes from different regions in a single AWS cluster.

However it is still possible to run clusters in [multiple zones](https://kubernetes.io/docs/setup/best-practices/multiple-zones/#walkthrough):

> Kubernetes 1.2 adds support for running a single cluster in multiple
>   failure zones (GCE calls them simply “zones”, AWS calls them
>   “availability zones”, here we’ll refer to them as “zones”).
>
> Multizone support is deliberately limited: a single Kubernetes cluster
>   can run in multiple zones, but only within the same region (and cloud
>   provider).

I hope it helps.

Comment: As I said: `Kubernetes cluster can run in multiple zones, but only within the same region (and cloud provider)`. Using `kubeadm` or not will not make a difference.

Answer (score 0):

If you are deploying your own kubernetes cluster then yes it's possible to create EC2 instances in one region as master nodes and EC2 instances in another region as worker nodes. Just that you need to ensure they are reachable by ensuring security groups, public IPs for EC2 instances or VPC peering etc.

**Edit:**

One thing to note is when you do `kubeadm init` on master node you need to add public IP of master node as a parameter because otherwise kubeadm will only generate certificate for private IP of master node.

```
kubeadm init --apiserver-cert-extra-sans=PUBLIC-IP-OF-MASTER-NODE --control-plane-endpoint=PUBLIC-IP-OF-MASTER-NODE
```

Once you do this the certificate genearated will be valid for Public IP of the master node and you should be able to join a worker node using the public IP of master node.

Verify that the IP that you are using to `kubeadm join` is listed in `X509v3 Subject Alternative Name:` section of the certificate using command in master node.

```
openssl x509 -in /etc/kubernetes/pki/apiserver.crt -text -noout
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/209427/discussion-on-answer-by-arghya-sadhu-in-kubernetes-whether-it-is-possible-to-cre).

Comment: @argya-sadhu, Is it possible to go with NLB(private subnet) in one region for api server (master) and keeping workers in 2 regions? connecting via vpc peering?